# How to get cellid in Symbian

Tags: qt, symbian, cellular-network

I'm new to Symbian, currently I done the same with j2me with the following code for getting the cellid, like that. Is there any way to get the device id that will excute in Qt SDK?

```
if(out== null ||out.equals("null")|| out.equals(""))
                out = System.getProperty("com.nokia.mid.cellid");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [QtMobility API](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtmobility-1.2/index.html)s to get the cell ID:

```
#include <QSystemNetworkInfo>

QtMobility::QSystemNetworkInfo netInfo;
int cellId = netInfo.cellId();
```

Remember to add Qt Mobility to your .pro file:

```
CONFIG += mobility
MOBILITY += systeminfo
```

Hope this helps!

Best regards